# Можно ли создать индекс на представление

Tags: sql, postgresql

На сколько я понимаю создать индекс можно только на материализованное представление. Прав ли я, или есть какие-то способы создания индекса на обычное представление.

Comment: На обычное нет, на [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html) можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В нынешней архитектуре `PostgreSQL` невозможно даже если не касаться любых вопросов о поддержании актуальности данных такого индекса при обновлениях нижележащих таблиц.

Все реализуемые в `PostgreSQL` индексы должны следовать [`Index Access Method API`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexam.html), который в свою очередь требует, чтобы поиск по индексу возвращал `TID` - `tuple id`, физический адрес строки в датафайлах таблицы.

У `view` нет физического представления данных на диске. Следовательно не может быть `TID` строки, следовательно невозможно сделать `Index Access Method`. Поэтому нет, поверх `view` индекс построить не выйдет.

У [`Materialized Views`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) физическое представление есть и индексы по ним реализованы. По правде говоря, индексы и вовсе не знают, построены они на таблице или материализованном представлении, для них это одно и то же.